# Analysis of "I woke up tired."

Tags: predicate, linking-verbs

"I woke up tired."

We have subject/(phrasal) verb/adjective.

So this looks like a linking verb with a predicate adjective. ("I am tired", "I became tired", "He seemed tired"). But since when is 'woke up' a linking verb? Is there a finite list of linking verbs or is it open? And I thought that a linking verb wasn't a 'doing' verb but 'woke up' seems like a 'doing' verb.

Note also that "I woke tired" or "I awoke tired" doesn't seem right. Why does the phrasal verb work but not the single word versions? Is it just usage?

And please don't say that 'tired' is an adverb because plainly it isn't, for any number of reasons--morphology being just the obvious one.

Comment: But she rolled over and went back to sleep.

Comment: She woke up alert. Raise High the Roofbeams, Carpenters [and Seymour]. :). But don't be struck dumb. Action verbs followed by adjectives are used in English to refer to states one finds oneself in that answer the question how (like an adverb).  I put up a whole list of them the other day. This is exactly the same structure.  I am not going to **wax poetic** but isn't this horse pretty dead?

Comment: @Lambie - How is it possible for a dead horse to be pretty?

Comment: I don't believe it's the same structure at all. "She made him tired"--there is a causative verb, and a direct object. "I woke up tired"--'woke up' here is an intransitive verb. (In another sentence it could be transitive--"I woke him up".) And 'tired' doesn't modify 'woke up' in the conventional sense--it doesn't show how you woke up, it shows how you were when you woke up. That's what you seem to be saying, and it's a very different structure to "He shot (made) Sam dead." He caused Sam to be in the state of being dead, but upon awaking he existed in the state of being tired.

Comment: It's as fundamental a distinction as the distinction between transitive and intransitive verbs, or between adverbs and adjectives (that is, not all that fundamental really, but as fundamental as grammar gets).

Comment: @Hot Licks I see you got my drift straight. To wake up tired is like to go down fast. Action verbs can be transitive or intransitive.....Just come clean, would ya'll? :)

Comment: Quoting from here--What are all the words that make up a complete list of linking verbs in English?--"Moving on, once you get to similar constructions with say 'become' ('Bob became warm'), 'pass' ('she passed unnoticed'), 'blush' ('the rose blushed pink') 'escape' ('she escaped unscathed') the 'link-like' verb, as Cobuild says, now has semantic weight."  If 'tired' is an adjective to 'woke up', why not just say 'woke up tiredly'. Surely there must be a difference?

Comment: Just come across the term 'resultative verb' in relation to my above comment. However, I don't think 'woke up tired' fits this idea, because the subject is tired despite sleeping, not because of it. Or are they tired as a result of waking up (too early)? The key question is, what is the relation of 'tired' to 'woke up'? It's not one of manner. Can there be an 'anti-resultative' relation, one where you note the opposite of the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

'Tired' may not be an adverb, but it is being used adverbially.

Note that a comma makes 'I woke, tired' work.

'I woke [up], [being] tired.' {tired = passive participle; cf. I was tired when I woke}

'I woke [up] the baby.' {the baby = direct object}

Comment: This question is the same as the one asked the other day re: shot dead. Yes, it is being used as an adverb even though it is an adjective. And I believe the question may have been asked by the same person.

Comment: There is a difference: 'He was shot [to be] dead' is related to the object complement {cf. 'She shot him [to be] dead'}

Comment: No, it isn't. It is the same structure. She shot him dead is not short for she shot him to be dead. That is agrammatical in any case.

Comment: 'She shot him dead' is the same structure as 'She woke him tired', but that 2nd sentence is 'agrammatical'.  'She shot him dead' does contain two clauses: 'He is dead' and 'She shot him' or 'She shot [to make] that he is dead'.  My '[to be]' is grammatical; just archaic since invention of the object complement.  Note that 'She shot him, to be dead' would be adverbial and shift the death to her.

Comment: She woke him tired is not grammatical in English. Your explanations seem to be veering further off course....:)

Comment: You're not listening: 'She woke him tired' is NOT grammatical, but it IS the same structure as 'She shot him dead'; therefore the structure must be different at some level.  That level is the level of the object complement, which involves eliding 'to be[come]'.

Comment: If it is not grammatical, it cannot be used as a comparison. I only compare comparables. He was shot dead; they were struck dumb; they were tinkled pink. Those are the same structure, for example.

Comment: In "I shot him dead", 'dead' is an object complement. In "I woke up tired" there is no object--unless you see it as some reflexive construction where 'I' is both subject and object. 'Tired' doesn't relate to the manner of 'woke up', so how can it be adverbial? 'Tired' relates back to 'I'. In "I woke up screaming" 'screaming' could definitely be adverbial. But "I woke up black and blue"…how can 'black and blue' be adverbial to 'woke up'? I can only see it as adverbial if you stretch the definition of 'adverb' well beyond what most grammarians give. I'll do it if you'll do it...

Comment: The more I think about it, the more it seems to me this way. To 'wake up' is a point of transition, of becoming--the moment when a human becomes aware again. So 'woke up' can be used like the verb 'become'--a linking verb. 'Woke up black and blue'--in the sense that the human only becomes aware of it at that moment, it is a moment of 'becoming' black and blue. 'Woke up tired'--doubly a 'becoming' moment, because if you'd stayed asleep, you probably wouldn't be tired. So I say: linking verb.

Comment: "I watched, dumbstruck" - the verb need not be linking, but the adverbial is always 'linked' via an elided 'being'; "I woke [up], [being] black and blue".

Comment: As soon as you put a comma in it becomes a parenthetical, and grammar becomes essentially irrelevant. "I watched, wondering idly if there was life on Mars." "I woke up, black and blue." But as soon as you take the commas out--"I woke up black and blue"--you have what works as a simple sentence. And I'm uncomfortable constantly assuming implied text. It smacks of simply rewriting sentences to suit. "I went to bed poor. I woke up a rich man."<Whoops! Just opened up a new can of worms. But 'rich man' looks to me like a PN.

Comment: Adding the comma shows that it is adverbial.  Without the comma, it is still adverbial -- unless you think it is the direct object: "I woke up black and blue" means that you woke two things named 'black' and 'blue'!  PS about elision: the elided stuff is always the simplest that can be assumed (verb = 'to be', etc.)  It isn't necessary to undo the elision if the decode process inherently handles it; just as the encode process need not ever generate words and then elide them, so long as the process 'knows' what the decoder will assume.

Answer (score 1):

I think *tired* is being used as a perfect passive participle - "I woke up [having been] tired." In which case, *woke up* is a simple verb and tired is just an adjective describing *I*.

Comment: There is no having been tired. The idea is you wake up and upon waking your state or condition is tired.

Comment: @Nick - You are right about passive participle, but not about perfect; "I woke up [and I was] tired."  cf. (active participle) "I woke up [and I was] smiling."